# Symfony JSON output including field name

Tags: php, json, symfony

I'm trying to pull a value from my DB in the field 'action', it is a JSON string however I'm storing it as a single value for now, this is it:

```
'command'=>'get','target'=>'location'
```

However when I pull it from the DB it includes the field name, which I don't want, see below:

```
[{"action":"'command'=>'get','target'=>'location'"}]
```

My code is here:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();   
    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $q = $query->select('z.action')
    ->from('AppBundle:ZeusUsers', 'z')
    ->where('z.id = ?1')
    ->setParameter(1, $id)
    ->getQuery();


    $action = $q->getResult();
    return new Response(json_encode($action));
```

So I just need to know how to grab the field value not including the field name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this method **getSingleScalarResult()**

but remember that if it wouldn't find anything it will throw exception

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#single-scalar-hydration

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `getSingleResult()` instead of `getResult()` to get value of your field. It will throw exception if there are no results found or there are more than one result (`setMaxResults(1)` will remedy this part) though.

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php#L802

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference